# After clicking Back button, retain search data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, search, back

I have a index action and its corresponding page.
Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchString, string searchField)
    {
         var data = --data from db--
         ViewBag.searchString = searchString;
         ViewBag.searchField = searchField;
         int pageSize = 15;
         int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                switch (searchField)
                {
                    case "firstname":
                    data = data.where(x => x.firstname == searchString);
                    break;
                    case "lastname":
                    data = data.where(x => x.lastname == lastname);
                    break;
                    default:
                    data = data.where(x => x.firstname == searchString);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                switch ()
                {
                   code for ajax search call
                }
            }

            return View(code for view);      
    }
```

I tried to store the search data with session variables. like

```
Session["searchString"] = searchString;
Session["searchField"] = searchField;
```

And give the session variables to search. In my project all action will be redirected to index action after completing the action functions. In that scenario, all data should be fetched but the session variables will be searched and searched data is showing. I want to show searched data on clicking back button and to show all data on redirection.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What back button? browser back button?

Comment: Yes, the browser back button

Comment: When you click the back button, it will go to your index action?

Comment: yeah sure. it will go to the index action ith searchString and searchField values as null

Answer (score -1):

You can put `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` on the action where you want to be hit on the server once you click the back button. Without caching the page, the browser will try to hit the server to get the contents instead of loading the previous content in the browser cache which will not hit your controller action.

Comment: Explain what happened?

Comment: on clicking back button, search data is not retained

Comment: It is because this lines, `ViewBag.searchString = searchString;` `ViewBag.searchField = searchField;`. Do you expect that the searcField and searchString parameters to have a value? Of course not, you should set the viewbag from the session data that you set if those are existing.